# Cumulocity Rapsberry PI - Connection problems

Tags: linux, cumulocity

I installed the Cumulocity Linux Agent on my Rapsberry PI, but I'm not able to register them on the Cumulocity platform. The platform stay in status Waiting for connection". To find out whats wrong I started the Cumulocity agent in Debug mode and found the following snip after the initializing the driver list:

```
"java.net ConnectionException: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt"
```

When take a look with nslookup anything looks fine. I've also switched off my firewall to check it out.
Has anyone any idea whats wrong? I've currently no connected sensors to my Pi.

Comment: Your question might be better suited for [the RaspberryPi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having an issue with the Rasberry pi agent too. Details at https://support.cumulocity.com/hc/en-us/articles/206926707-Ask-developer-questions-on-stackoverflow-com

The agent is unable to locate the path to JAVA_HOME and I think that spans off related issues .Pl there is not enough documentation on the configuration file

Comment: what is the answer, then?

Answer (score 0):

Check `/usr/share/cumulocity-rpi-agent/cfg/cumulocity.properties` 
file and uncomment the host and add your hostname